# Equivalence of two different Taylor formulas

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

In Fitzpatrick's book Advanced Calculus there is the following Taylor formula with a proof : $$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{f^{(k)} (x_0)}{k!} (x-x_0)^k + \dfrac{f^{(n+1)} (c)}{(n+1)!} (x-x_0)^{n+1}.$$

However in Jean-Michel Morel's book Ramanujan Summation of Divergent Series, there is another one without a proof : $$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{f^{(k)} (0)}{k!} (x)^k + \int_0^x \dfrac{f^{(n+1)} (t)}{n!} (x-t)^n dt.$$

How to derive the second one from the first one?

Comment: The second one is centered at $0$, so $x_0 = 0$.  We have here two different forms for the remainder.  Both forms should be found in calculus textbooks.  But I would not try to deduce the second one from the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
$$
I_n = \int_0^x \frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{n!} (x-t)^n \, dt.
$$
By the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have for $n = 0$
$$
I_0 = \int_0^x f'(t) \, dt = f(x) - f(0)
$$ and for $n \geq 1$, we can apply integration by parts to yield
\begin{align*}
I_n &= \int_0^x \frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{n!} (x-t)^n \, dt \\&= \left[ \frac{f^{(n)}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^n \right]_{t=0}^{t=x} - \int_0^x \frac{f^{(n)}(t)}{n!} \left[ - n (x-t)^{n-1} \right] \, dt \\
&= -\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!} + \int_0^x \frac{f^{(n)}(t)}{(n-1)!} (x-t)^{n-1} \, dt \\
&= -\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!} + I_{n-1}.
\end{align*}
Thus, by a straightforward inductive argument,
$$
I_n = - \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(x)}{k!} + I_0 = - \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(x)}{k!} + f(x)
$$
from which the desired identity follows.